# Getting additional UART ports for MKR 1500

Tags: arduino, arduino-mkr1000

I have spent 4 days and I can't get this working. I read a lot and still not get any closer. I need to have additional UART ports for Arduino MKR 1500. Not one, not two, I need to have MAX available UART ports. How many total devices I can connect using UART.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isyCn.png)

I see this table in my dreams at night, and I can't figure out how to use it. 
The only one I got succesfully working is example from Arduino web site:

```
Uart mySerial (&sercom3, 0, 1, SERCOM_RX_PAD_1, UART_TX_PAD_0);
```

Please help. 
I would appriciate if you just create a simple .ino file (WORKING!!!) with let's say 4 UARTs.
Please!!!

Also will the code work for this:

```
void SERCOM0_Handler()
{
  mySerial2.IrqHandler();
  mySerial3.IrqHandler();
}
```

Or I can only have one UART per SERCOM?

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SamdSercom

Comment: do you have `pinPeripheral(0, PIO_SERCOM);`?

Comment: and confusing is that 0 is TX and 1 is RX. the tutorial describes it wrong. the pads settings count, not the order in constructor or the comments at pinPeripheral cals

Comment: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=630415.msg4268149